# What is default value of updatePolicy in Maven

Tags: maven

In maven doc there is description of attribute "updatePolicy" in snapshots tag: 
https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.0/maven-settings/settings.html#snapshots

When I don't specify it in pom.xml maven is not complaining:

```
    <repository>
       <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
       </snapshots>
     <id>central</id>
     <url>http://artifactory.../artifactory/repo</url>
</repository>
```

So then I would expect there is a default value, but what is the default value?

Comment: The default is `daily` can be read here: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default is `daily` which is documented here https://maven.apache.org/settings.html